# ARR management and configuration on remote hosts

Tags: xml, iis, arr

I have a several MS Windows servers with IIS installed. What is the best way to manage and configure the existing applicationHost.config on them? We're usning them as Application Request Routing (ARR) - Reverse Proxy.
I'm considering Ansible with xml module or somthing DIY like C#\PowerShell\Python scripts.

Answer (score 0):

IIS web farm simplifies the provisioning, scaling, and management of multiple servers for administrators and hosting providers.
Please refer to the below link for details.
https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-farm-framework 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-arr/define-and-configure-an-application-request-routing-server-farm
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-arr/http-load-balancing-using-application-request-routing